# optimistic ui updates - react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-state-management

I imagine this is a basic in react but I'm not sure how to get it to work, basically when I delete, create or edit anything in my components I want the change to happen in realtime without refreshing the page, I've achieved it at some level with the search function but not entirely sure how to do with for the delete function for example:

Here is what I'm working with, how would I get this to work with my axios delete function?
Thanks

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchTournaments } from '../actions/tournaments';
import Item from './Item';
import EditTournament from './EditTournament';
import axios from 'axios';

import '../styles/Item.css';

class SearchAndDisplay extends React.PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchTournaments();
  }

  state = {
    searchCriteria: '',
    isLoading: false
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      searchCriteria: event.target.value
    });
  };

  async handleDelete(id) {
    const url = `http://localhost:4000/tournaments/`;

    await axios
      .delete(url + id)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  formatDate(date) {
    let options = {
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'numeric',
      day: 'numeric',
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: 'numeric',
      second: 'numeric',
      hour12: false
    };

    let newDate = new Date(Date.parse(date));
    let format = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('default', options).format(newDate);

    return format;
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ searchCriteria: event.target.value });
  };

  renderList() {
    let tournmentsArray = this.props.tournaments;

    const filterTournaments = tournmentsArray.filter(item =>
      item.name.includes(this.state.searchCriteria)
    );

    if (filterTournaments === undefined || filterTournaments.length === 0) {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className="notFound">
            Something went wrong.
            <br />
            <button
              className="notFoundButton"
              onClick={() => {
                this.setState({ searchCriteria: '' });
              }}
            >
              Retry
            </button>
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    } else {
      return filterTournaments.map(item => (
        <Item
          key={item.name}
          name={item.name}
          organizer={item.organizer}
          participants={Object.values(item.participants)}
          game={item.game}
          start={this.formatDate(item.startDate)}
        >
          <div className="buttonBar">
            <EditTournament id={item.id} />
            <button
              className="button"
              onClick={() => {
                if (
                  window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')
                ) {
                  this.handleDelete(item.id);
                }
              }}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
          </div>
        </Item>
      ));
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <input
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          className="input"
          placeholder="Search..."
          id="searchField"
          value={this.state.searchCriteria}
        />
        <div className="row">{this.renderList()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ tournaments }) {
  return {
    tournaments: Object.values(tournaments).flat()
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  fetchTournaments
})(SearchAndDisplay);
```

unlike delete the create and edit data is handled by redux like so:

Create tournament:

```
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import '../styles/promptForms.css';
import '../styles/Header.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createTournaments } from '../actions/tournaments';

class CreateTournamentPromptFrom extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showHide: false
    };
  }
  createTournamentButton() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          className="genericButton"
          onClick={() => this.setState({ showHide: true })}
        >
          CREATE TOURNAMENT
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderInput = ({ input, label }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>{label}</label>
        <br />
        <input className="promptInput" {...input} autoComplete="off" />
      </div>
    );
  };

  onSubmit = formValues => {
    this.props.createTournaments(formValues);
  };

  render() {
    const { showHide } = this.state;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className={`overlay ${showHide ? 'toggle' : ''} `} />

        <div className={`promptBox ${showHide ? 'toggle' : ''} `}>
          <h3>localhost:3000 says</h3>
          <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
            <Field
              name="name"
              component={this.renderInput}
              label="Enter Tournament:"
            />

            <button className="okayButton">OK</button>
          </form>
          <button
            className="cancelButton"
            onClick={() => this.setState({ showHide: false })}
          >
            Cancel
          </button>
        </div>
        {this.createTournamentButton()}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const formWrapped = reduxForm({
  form: 'promptForm'
})(CreateTournamentPromptFrom);

export default connect(null, { createTournaments })(formWrapped);
```

actions:

```
import {
  FETCH_TOURNAMENTS,
  FETCH_TOURNAMENT,
  CREATE_TOURNAMENT,
  EDIT_TOURNAMENT
} from './types';

import { API_TOURNAMENTS_URL } from '../constants/api';
import axios from 'axios';

export const fetchTournaments = () => async dispatch => {
  const response = await axios.get(API_TOURNAMENTS_URL);

  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_TOURNAMENTS,
    payload: response.data.flat()
  });
};

export const fetchTournament = id => async dispatch => {
  const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/tournaments/${id}`);

  dispatch({ type: FETCH_TOURNAMENT, payload: response.data });
};

export const createTournaments = formValues => async dispatch => {
  const response = await axios.post(API_TOURNAMENTS_URL, {
    ...formValues
  });

  dispatch({ type: CREATE_TOURNAMENT, payload: response.data });
};

export const editTournaments = (id, formValues) => async dispatch => {
  const response = await axios.patch(
    `http://localhost:4000/tournaments/${id}`,
    formValues
  );

  dispatch({ type: EDIT_TOURNAMENT, payload: response.data });
};
```

reducers:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

import {
  FETCH_TOURNAMENT,
  CREATE_TOURNAMENT,
  FETCH_TOURNAMENTS,
  EDIT_TOURNAMENT,
  DELETE_TOURNAMENT
} from '../actions/types';

export default (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_TOURNAMENT:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload };
    case FETCH_TOURNAMENTS:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload };
    case CREATE_TOURNAMENT:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload };
    case EDIT_TOURNAMENT:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload };
    case DELETE_TOURNAMENT:
      return _.omit(state, action.payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: I would use the index for the key i think, to make sure name wouldnt be duplicates.. .map((item,index) =>

Comment: @Rmaxx Don't use index as react key, especially if you expect to mutate the array being mapped over. This ***will** cause rendering issues because the index isn't associated to the data, i.e. if you delete element at index 3 all the elements shift up an index, but the index (key) is still the same so react bails on rerendering those elements and the UI is now out-of-sync with the underlying data.

Comment: True, butIf he really deletes it he could rerender the new array he gets, he's not using state.he could also use the id btw, name just doesnt sound unique enough

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do using `forceUpdate()` (Since you don't want to use state):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
      this.items = [
        {id: 1, name: "item 1"},
        {id: 2, name: "item 2"},
      ];

    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
  }

  handleDelete(index) {
    const newState = [...this.items];
    delete newState[index];
    // or
    // newState.splice(index, 1);
    this.items = newState;
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.items.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <div>
                {item.name}
                <button onClick={() => this.handleDelete(index)}>Delete item</button>
              </div>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Just pass the index in the map method :
`...map((item, index) => ...);`

Do it in the `then()` after your axios call.

Note that the documentation highly advice you to **avoid** using `forceUpdate()` when you can, so you really should use a state for this, I don't see any good reason for you not to use it here.

Here is a [quick repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-if4fme?file=index.js).

Comment: I'm not using state for my items though so this solution doesn't fit my criteria :/

Comment: Actually you can use `forceUpdate()`, it seems to works pretty well, but i'm not sure if it is a good thing and how good it is about performance.

Answer (score 1):

To "optimistically" delete an item from state you'll need to immediately delete it from state to reflect the change right away in the UI. ***BUT*** you will need to add extra redux state to "hold" a pending delete with your backend. When the delete is successful you clear the held delete, if it fails you clear the held delete and add it back in to your regular data (and perhaps display some error message or toast, etc..).

I see you don't do the delete via redux, so use local component state and you'll have to filter your tournament data when rendering.

```
class SearchAndDisplay extends PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchTournaments();
  }

  state = {
    searchCriteria: "",
    isLoading: false,
    optimisticTournaments: null // <-- state to hold temp "deleted" data
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      searchCriteria: event.target.value
    });
  };

  async handleDelete(id) {
    console.log("delete id", id);
    // optimistically remove element
    this.setState({
      optimisticTournaments: this.props.tournaments.filter(
        item => item.id !== id
      )
    });

    await axios
      .delete(url + id)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        // Need to create a call back to let parent know element was deleted
        this.props.deleteSuccess(id);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        alert("Failed to delete");
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ optimisticTournaments: null });
      });
  }

  formatDate(date) {
    let options = {
      year: "numeric",
      month: "numeric",
      day: "numeric",
      hour: "numeric",
      minute: "numeric",
      second: "numeric",
      hour12: false
    };

    let newDate = new Date(Date.parse(date));
    let format = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("default", options).format(newDate);

    return format;
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ searchCriteria: event.target.value });
  };

  renderList() {
    let tournmentsArray =
      this.state.optimisticTournaments || this.props.tournaments;

    const filterTournaments = tournmentsArray.filter(item =>
      item.name.includes(this.state.searchCriteria)
    );

    if (filterTournaments === undefined || filterTournaments.length === 0) {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className="notFound">
            Something went wrong.
            <br />
            <button
              className="notFoundButton"
              onClick={() => {
                this.setState({ searchCriteria: "" });
              }}
            >
              Retry
            </button>
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    } else {
      return filterTournaments.map(item => (
        <Item
           key={item.name}
           name={item.name}
           organizer={item.organizer}
           participants={Object.values(item.participants)}
           game={item.game}
           start={this.formatDate(item.startDate)}
         >
          <div className="buttonBar">
            <EditTournament id={item.id} />
            <button
              className="button"
              onClick={() => {
                if (
                  window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
                ) {
                  this.handleDelete(item.id);
                }
              }}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
          </div>
        </Item>
      ));
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <input
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          className="input"
          placeholder="Search..."
          id="searchField"
          value={this.state.searchCriteria}
        />
        <div className="row">{this.renderList()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit optimistic delete]

Comment: Drew Reese, the delete isn't handled by redux yes but how would I do the `create tournments` with redux for example. I've provided my redux data in the question.

Comment: Also I think the code you provided might be bugged as it says failed to delete on both your sandbox and my code

Comment: @rednate95 Oops, yeah, accidentally left the axios call uncommented out in the sandbox when I was copying into SO. Fixed that in sandbox. Moved the `tournaments` in the sandbox back out as a prop so internally it's treated the same as if provided from redux store.